# Dialogflow - setAgent() error, cannot create property createStub of undefined

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, nestjs, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm seeing the following error when I try to `setAgent` using the Node SDK within a NestJS backend.

```
Cannot read property 'createStub' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createStub' of undefined
    at Object.initialize (/path/here/Dirname/app-name/server/node_modules/@google-cloud/dialogflow/build/src/v2beta1/agents_client.js:201:41)
    at Object.setAgent (/path/here/Dirname/app-name/server/node_modules/@google-cloud/dialogflow/build/src/v2beta1/agents_client.js:341:14)
```

Environment

- macOS `10.15.7`
- node `v12.16.2`
- typescript: `^3.7.4`
- dialogflow `^3.3.0`
- googleapis: `^64.0.0`
- google-gax: `^2.9.2`

---

My service file looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { google } from '@google-cloud/dialogflow/build/protos/protos';
import { v2beta1 as dialogflow } from '@google-cloud/dialogflow';
import { WinstonLogger } from '../logger/logger.service';

import Agent = google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.Agent;
import ApiVersion = Agent.ApiVersion;
import ISetAgentRequest = google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.ISetAgentRequest;
import MatchMode = Agent.MatchMode;
import Tier = Agent.Tier;

@Injectable()
export class ServiceName {

  constructor(
    private readonly logger: WinstonLogger,
  ) {
    this.logger.setContext('Service Name');
  }

createAgent(agentParent: string):any {
   
    const agentPayload: ISetAgentRequest = {
      agent: {
        parent: `${agentParent}`,
        displayName: 'test display name',
        defaultLanguageCode: 'en-US',
        supportedLanguageCodes: ['en-US'],
        timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
        description: 'test description',
        avatarUri: 'url-added-here',
        enableLogging: true,
        matchMode: MatchMode.MATCH_MODE_ML_ONLY,
        classificationThreshold: 0.3,
        apiVersion: ApiVersion.API_VERSION_V2_BETA_1,
        tier: Tier.TIER_ENTERPRISE
      }
    };

    const result = dialogflow.AgentsClient.prototype // <-- only way to satisfy typescript by adding prototype:
      .setAgent(agentPayload)
      .catch((e) => {
        this.logger.warn('-----> Error: ' + e);
      });

    return result[0];
  }
}
```

Adding the `.prototype` before `.setAgent()` helped me remove the typescript compilation errors - open gh issue for this: [link](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow/issues/672)

I did look in `agents_client.js` lines 201 & 341 but couldn't figure it out.

Thank you to anyone with any ideas

Comment: Interestingly I get the same error when I attempt to `getAgent()` too..

Comment: Hello, can you share the full service code, in order to reproduce? The above, gives me TS errors on `createAgent` and `agentParent`.

Comment: Hi @milia - I did leave out some default Nest code, I have added that to the code sample. Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: From the error message, it seems to come from the setagent's payload. The timezone used is not supported and failed when I tried it. When I tried with the correct format 'America/Los_Angeles', it worked fine. Could you try and see if it works for you or if there is any other issue?

Comment: @Ksign - I made the suggested change to `timeZone` and the error unfortunately persisted with the same message.

Comment: It would be good to know if you are able to do this from the [Try this API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects/setAgent) feature on the setagent method page for the v2beta1 version. Which is where I tried with your payload config. I am no nodejs expert unfortunately. Can I run your code from my shell as it is?

Comment: @Ksign - That did work when logged in as GCP organization admin but the authentication being used is for a service account that has the editor role.

Comment: This was to ensure that your payload was correct and that the API works as expected. Your issue seem to be in your code or in the library for which you have already raised an issue with the engineers that are maintaining it. I suggest you ping them again to keep the issue alive.